# Left-handed and right-handed helicity, can you explained well the phenomenon of chirality simply?

Tags: quantum-spin, spinors, chirality, helicity

Chirality, helicity as a projection of its spin vector .. that becomes a kind of 'virtual spin'?

I often confuse them: but the particles 'spin' on the right or left, or is the projection of .. what? *Left* or *right* is a simbolic term to describe a particle degrees of freedom?

Comment: Helicity is projection of spin on the momentum axis. Chirality is transformation rule with respect to Lorentz group. For masless particles these two properties coincide.